# given input a sequence to determine if it is increasing or decreasing

Tags: bash, shell

hi given a sequence I have to check if it is increasing or decreasing, I did it but it doesn't work for me how can I solve it?

```
#!/bin/bash
tot=0
numeri=0
media=0
cresc=0
decresc=0

for number in $@ 
do
    tot=$((tot+number))
    numeri=$((numeri+1))
done
 
echo TOTALE = $tot
media=$((tot/numeri))
echo MEDIA = $media


if [ $cresc -eq 0 ]
then echo SEQ. CRESCENTE
else echo SEQ. DECRESCENTE
fi
```

output:

```
user insert: 1 2 4
system response: the sequence is increasing
```

user insert: 4 3 2

```
system response: the sequence is decreasing
```

Comment: `cresc` is not being set anywhere

Comment: Always first test your script to https://shellcheck.net before asking here. Thanks

Comment: Please post sample input and expected output

Comment: @GillesQuénot the output is that the user types 123 and the system returns that and increasing......I tried it before inserting it here and it doesn't work for me otherwise I wouldn't insert it above

Comment: Compared with **what** ?

Comment: @GillesQuénot what must appear is that if the user enters 1 2 3 the system must say that it is increasing if instead I have 3 2 1 descending

Comment: Add this to original post, **not in comment**

Comment: What if they enter `3 1 2`?

Comment: @PaulHodges it's neither ascending nor descending... but nothing about ascending and descending works for me

Comment: BTW, always quote `"$@"` -- unquoted it behaves just like an unquoted `$*`

Comment: @saretta2, take a close look at the answer you accepted. You'll see that it thinks 10 is a smaller number than 2, because it's comparing numbers as strings instead of as numbers; so it's sometimes prone to giving outright wrong answers.

Answer (score 1):

##### What about this simple and readable one?

```
#!/bin/bash

crescente=0
decrescente=${#@}
dec=$decrescente

for number; do
    if [[ ! $number =~ ^-?[0-9]+$ ]]; then
        echo "C'È ALMENO QUALCOSA CHE NON È UN NUMERO" >&2
        exit 1
    fi

    if [[ $last ]]; then
        if ((last < number)); then
            ((crescente++))
        elif ((last > number)); then
            ((decrescente++))
        fi
    fi
    last=$number
done

if ((crescente && decrescente == dec)); then
    echo "SEQ. CRESCENTE"
elif ((descrecente < dec && crescente == 0)); then
    echo "SEQ. DECRESCENTE"
else
    echo "NON ORDINATO" >&2
    exit 1
fi
```

`((...))` is an arithmetic command, which returns an exit status of 0 if the expression is nonzero, or 1 if the expression is zero. Also used as a synonym for "let", if side effects (assignments) are needed. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ArithmeticExpression.

---

##### Example output

```
$ ./seq.sh 1 2 x
CÈ ALMENO QUALCOSA CHE NON È UN NUMERO
$ ./seq.sh 1 2 3
SEQ. CRESCENTE
$ ./seq.sh 3 2 1
SEQ. DECRESCENTE
$ ./seq.sh 3 2 1 0
SEQ. DECRESCENTE
$ ./seq.sh 3 2 1 0 -1
SEQ. DECRESCENTE
$ ./seq.sh -42 42 $((2**42))
SEQ. CRESCENTE
$ ./seq.sh 3 5 2
NON ORDINATO
```

Comment: sorry but what is $last?

Comment: `last=$number` is assigned in the end of each loop. It needed to compare current value with the latest one

Comment: thanks and however if I type 3 2 1 it tells me unordered sequence

Comment: Are you sure you use bash? How you run the script in which shell?

Comment: I use the mac bash shell

Comment: Try using bash. Default is zsh

Comment: You put bash tag anyway...

Comment: sisi but I already use it, Everything works for me except if I insert a descending sequence it tells me that it is not ordered

Comment: Looks strange. Tested it as as well. See sample output

Comment: in fact for this it seems strange to me because it works correctly for you

Comment: okay, the mac is a bit like that... thanks a lot anyway :)

Comment: Can you fill https://hastebin.com/ with : `cat script.sh` `bash script.sh 3 2 1` and the output?

Comment: https://ideone.com

Comment: sorry I had inserted it:https://ideone.com/f2iqFC

Comment: This is a **modified version from you**, mine works. Accept this answer and add a new question. You have modified my variables